# How to extract value from a spark dataframe and add it to a second one as a column?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I have 2 large spark dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has a column with a `colName` name that has only one distinct value. I need to add this column to the `df2`. I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way to do that?

My idea is to use `limit()` or `first()` on the `df1` and then `crossJoin` with the `df2` but it would trigger an action.

```
val newDf = df1.select(colName).limit(1)
df2.crossJoin(newDf)
```

Comment: You could collect the first row of `df1` and extract the value to then add it in `df2` without any join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some ways to increase performance.

1. As @Gaël J mentioned you can extract first row value and create new column with it.
2. You can broadcast the smaller dataframe and to join, this will reduce the amount of data shuffled during the join.
3. Reducing number of partitions of `df2` dataframe according to your executor memory.

Below are the `df1` and `df2`.

[image]

Getting first row value and creating **newDf**.

```
import  org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val  value = df1.select("colName").first()(0)
val  newDf = df2.withColumn("colName",lit(value).cast("INT"))
newDf.show()
```

[image]

Using **Broadcast**.

```
import  org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val  newDf = df1.select("colName").limit(1)
val  broadcastNewDf = broadcast(newDf)
val  resultDf = df2.crossJoin(broadcastNewDf)
resultDf.show()
```

[image]